# looking for an open source text editor with very fast 'search in files' capability

Tags: full-text-search, text-editor

I have this 100.000 files codebase that i need to tame and i need to very often search for the occurences of a specific function call or a function definition.

Currently with notepad++ it takes me more than 5 minutes to do the search.

Do you know of a programmer's editor that would make the job ?

Thank you for your help

Jerome Wagner

Comment: @Alan Haggai Alavi - I don't think that this is a duplicate of that particular question, given that this one is about a large NUMBER of files, not about individual large files.

Comment: @Sohnee: You are right. No options to undo the close though.

Comment: if you are mostly interested in inspection function definitions and references then better keywords for you are 'documentation generators'. you will get speed *and* extra functionality.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you should use a specific search tool for the search, rather than a text-editor...

Depending on your platform, there are various tools available such as GREP (command line), Windows Search Service (which creates indexes of the files in advance to make queries faster) or even Google desktop search.

http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=file%20search%20tool

(Tip: Add Windows / Linux etc to the search)

Comment: 100k files is definitely time for a search engine

Comment: @bemace, ...or documentation generator, see my answer

Answer (score 1):

grep should be most forward implementation of what you are looking for.
I tested it on an older system with 11k source files and it took 20s.

Assuming avg file size of 1k you are dealing with 100MB of text. Assuming avg file size of 10k you are dealing with 1GB of text.

Searching that much data will take time.

If you expect to be much faster then 5 minutes you will need to build indexes.

There are specialized tools that will allow you to do that:

- [doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/)
- [cscope](http://cscope.sourceforge.net/)
- [sxt](http://sxt.freeservers.com/intro_.htm)

For more visit [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_documentation_generators)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Grep is good and popular to be integrated in many tool on many platform.
One free for win:http://www.pspad.com/

> The BEST one I ever used is built into
>   PSPad (www.pspad.com / freeware) it
>   displays a list and you can change
>   anything or all the strings, or search
>   and see where they appear. You can
>   also search specific directories only.

Answer (score 0):

You can also be interested in [ack](http://www.betterthangrep.com), or cscope.

You can integrate ack inside vim with the following:

```
set grepprg=ack
nnoremap <f1> :grep<space>
nnoremap <f1> :grepapp<space>
```